# ASP.Net web forms with ServiceStack.Net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, servicestack

I have a ASP.Net web application with around 100 forms. The coding is in VB.Net. We now want to add servicestack.net services inside this application. We want to do this so that session can be shared between the asp.net application and the web service and authentication can also be done via the web application. Please let me know if this is possible, if yes can one anyone  point me to a sample application or provide me with the web.config and global asax file configuration that I should use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, servicestack supports asp.net web forms. You can try this [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Host.AspNet/) . I don't really sure about session as service stack using something different mechanism for session. But yes you can share the session explained here in [session section](http://www.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/).

I hope this will help. Please let me know if any further details are needed.